# Usage of SSIS Script Component as source

Tags: c#, ssis

I am trying to get some basic code running. I am using a SSIS script component (source type). I have set up the component using the code in http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136060(v=sql.105).aspx (section: ADO.NET Source Example). However the following line is gnerating an error:

connMgr = this.Connections. MyADONETConnection;

'Connections' does not contain a definition for 'MyADONETConnection' and no extension method 'MyADONETConnection' accepting a first argument of type 'Connections' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have set up the connection and output columns as per the instructions.
Any thoughts appreciated.
Johnny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Bill is correct, in the Script Component editor, you have to explicitly add a reference to the Connection Manager you created in order to access it in  the script.

1. Open the editor for your Script Component.
2. Select the **Connection Managers** tab from the left.
3. Add a new entry for your *MyADONetConnection* to the Connection Managers list. You can name it anything you want, though generally you should name it the same as your connection manager for maintainability.
4. Now you can access this connection as a property of the Connections collection in your script.

Comment: In the Script Component, you can specify what Connection Manager(s) you'd like to expose to the underlying Script. In the OP's case, most likely they haven't followed the instructions under "Adding Connection Managers"

Comment: Many thanks. I hadn't set the Connection name - it defaults to "Connection". Was confusing the Connection manager name with the instance name - silly.